# using .env variables when configuring env.py file in alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Based on the posts I've seen this is the most common way to point the alembic.ini sqlalchemy.url to a desired db path in the alembic env.py file

```
import os

from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.

connection_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://<username>:<password>@localhost/test_server'

config = context.config
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', connection_string)
```

this works for me when the value is just one hardcoded string.
However, When I try to replace the username and password values with hidden variables coming from my .env file I am always receiving an operational error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "None" does not exist
```

```
username = os.environ.get("USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")

connection_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@localhost/test_server'

config = context.config
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', connection_string)
```

What am I doing wrong that is not allowing me to use my environment variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) (`pip install python-dotenv`) like so:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

username = os.environ.get("USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PASSWORD")
```

(dotenv doesn't have any external library dependencies which is nice)

Comment: right so I was missing the load_dotenv() script. That has fixed it for me. Thank you!